# Lost user password in Slackware 14.1, how to resolve encryption in /etc/shadow?

Tags: encryption

Usually I use my root account when working with my Linux server, however, I created a user account which I use far less frequently. However, I would like to use it for a task today, but I forgot the password since I rarely use the user account. I know the password is encrypted and stored in `/etc/shadow`, and I would like to know how to resolve the encryption so that I can proceed. My other option, I suppose, would be simply to delete the user account and create a new one.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately for you, it is not encryption, but a one way hash, so there is no way to actually reverse it. The only option you have is the brute force route, where you guess passwords and hash them until one matches.

There are tools which do this, like John the Ripper, or you can go down the route of rainbow tables, which effectively have the brute forcing done for you, but it can take a while.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is recover access to that account then you can probably just reset the user's password from the root account.

Comment: The objection was to my phrasing of my suggestion as an question. It is no longer couched in those terms. It is now a direct X not Y answer to the question. If that is also against desired standards then that is a, slightly bizarre to my mind, but valid criticism.